# How do you retrieve which "Type" each Opportunity StageName value is with the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, query, metadata

I can retrieve `Opportunity` field metadata, including picklist values, with the REST API like so:

```
[{"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Prospecting", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Prospecting"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Qualification", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Qualification"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Needs Analysis", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Needs Analysis"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Value Proposition", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Value Proposition"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Id. Decision Makers", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Id. Decision Makers"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Perception Analysis", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Perception Analysis"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Proposal/Price Quote", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Proposal/Price Quote"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Negotiation/Review", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Negotiation/Review"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Closed Won", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Closed Won"},
 {"active"=>true, "defaultValue"=>false, "label"=>"Closed Lost", "validFor"=>nil, "value"=>"Closed Lost"}]
```

But I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the "Type" metadata associated with each picklist value that you can see with the web interface:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to get that "Type" metadata using the REST API?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually data, not metadata, and you can query for it in the [`OpportunityStage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitystage.htm) object.

```
SELECT IsActive, IsClosed, IsWon FROM OpportunityStage
```

The `Type` field itself is not stored, but can be inferred from the `IsClosed` and `IsWon` fields. If `IsClosed` is false, the `Type` is `Open`. If `IsClosed` is true and `IsWon` is false, the `Type` is `Closed/Lost`. If `IsClosed` is true and `IsWon` is true, the `Type` is `Closed/Won`.

Comment: This is not related to the OP, however I felt it might be worth noting if you wanted to query the Opportunity and get the StageName's "Type", you can infer it from these values:

---> SELECT Name, IsWon, IsClosed FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1